# What is the proper way to raise exception and handle certain exception type in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I know **theoretically** how to create and handle exception. But in a big project a function can throw a lot of different exception.

### How do I manage to parse all the exceptions I can receive?

#### For example:

I am currently implementing a database client. And if a query ask for a bad table or a bad column I throw exception in the low level driver as follow:

```
throw MySQLException("message");
```

And this will result in throwing a `std::runtime_error` exception in the client's top level. So I added the following code to catch the exception:

```
try {
  execute(query);
}
catch(std::exception &e) {
  // How do I parse exception content?
}
```

But is there a better way than excrating info from the `e.what()` to figure out what kind of exception it is?
The objective is to make each sort of exception correspond to an error code (without modifiying the exception message).

*Link to tutorial will be weclome.*

Comment: if you find yourself using a `try` block a lot you might want to consider a [Lippencot function](https://cppsecrets.blogspot.ca/2013/12/using-lippincott-function-for.html)

Comment: Why should throwing throw MySQLException result in throwing std::runtime_error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple `catch` statements, like this:

```
try {
    execute(query);
}
catch (const my_custom_exception_type& e) {
}
catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {
}
catch (...) {
    // fallback - exception object is not any of the above types
}
```

Control will flow into the first `catch` block whose parameter type is compatible with the exception object type. If none match and there is no `...` catch-all, the exception will propagate out of that try/catch block. A more precise explanation of the exact try/catch behavior can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch):

> When an exception of type E is thrown by any statement in compound-statement, it is matched against the types of the formal parameters T of each catch-clause in handler-seq, in the order in which the catch clauses are listed. The exception is a match if any of the following is true:
>
> - E and T are the same type (ignoring top-level cv-qualifiers on T)
> - T is an lvalue-reference to (possibly cv-qualified) E
> - T is an unambiguous public base class of E
> - T is a reference to an unambiguous public base class of E
> - T is (possibly cv-qualified) U or const U& (since C++14), and U is a pointer or pointer to member (since C++17) type, and E is also a pointer or pointer to member (since C++17) type that is implicitly convertible to U by one or more of
>
>   - a standard pointer conversion other than one to a private, protected, or ambiguous base class
>   - a qualification conversion
>   - a function pointer conversion (since C++17)
> - T is a pointer or a pointer to member or a reference to a const pointer (since C++14), while E is std::nullptr_t.

You can also use [RTTI](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) to determine the type of `e` but avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: If so why when I don't catch my exception I get the following text: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'` and not `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MySQLException'` ? Is it due to inheritance or my exception may already have been caught and resend?

Comment: @GuillaumeMILAN I can't tell without seeing the full code. `std::terminate()` does print the concrete type name of the exception object even for custom exception types, at least in glibc (not sure if that printed text is part of the spec, I doubt it).

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you are directly looking for, but in regards to the statement that you made:

> `But in a big project a function can throw a lot of different exception.`

I have used this kind of design in a large project when building a 3D Graphics Engine. This does require a handful of classes though. Another thing to note is that my code was designed with windows specific in mind. I've commented parts that are window specific code that can be replaced with your specific OS implementation. Another thing is I've used `__FUNCTION__` in many of the output messages, you can replace that with `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` as for some reason windows and visual studio doesn't like it... You can also replace the namespace I used with your own namespace name. If this doesn't directly help you maybe at least the overall design might be of use. You can create a new project and use this as is just to see the generated console messages and the written log file. You can take some of the concepts from this, or you can expand and integrate your own specific error messages and exception types that are thrown into these classes that would make it suitable for your own purposes.

---

The following classes are integrated together where some of them can be used independently or in combination and should be thread safe for multithreading purposes.

> - ExceptionHandler - It uses the Logger class and is used to handle messages that are thrown and or sent to the Logger.
> - Logger - A derived class from Singleton. It logs to either the console, a text file or both. It uses the TextFileWriter to write to a text file.
> - Singleton - A base class that all Singleton Type classes are derived from.
> - TextFileWriter - A derived class from FileHandler. It writes to a text file.
> - FileHandler - A base class that all file handling type classes derive from.

---

**Example Program Using The Above Classes:**

```
#include "Logger.h"
#include "ExceptionHandler.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

enum ReturnCode {
    ReturnError = -1,
    ReturnOkay = 0
};

// helper function
void quitMessage() {
    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit.\n";
    std::cin.get();
}

// Example Class that uses the Logger & ExceptionHandler.
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;

    void printFooUsingExceptionHandler() {
        using namespace linx;
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " using ExceptionHandler" ) );
        // Or can be used this way
        // std::ostringstream stream;
        // stream << __FUNCTION__ << " using ExceptionHandler";
        // throw ExceptionHandler( stream );
    }

    void printFooNotUsingExceptionHandlerButUsingLogger() {
        using namespace linx;
        std::ostringstream stream;
        stream << __FUNCTION__ << " logging to logger, but not using ExceptionHandler";
        Logger::log( stream, Logger::TypeWarning ); // Can use TypeInfo, TypeWarning or TypeError pending on the use case.
    }
};

int main() {
    namespace lx = linx;
    using namespace lx;

    try {
        Logger logger( "logger.txt" );

        // last param is ommited as it is defaults to TypeInfo
        Logger::log( "This is basic info" ); 
        Logger::log( "This is a warning", Logger::TypeWarning );
        Logger::log( "This is an error", Logger::TypeError );
        Logger::log( "Basic console message", Logger::TypeConsole );    

        // Example of a class using the ExceptionHandler & Logger classes
        Foo f;
        // call this first; log to message but don't throw excpetion
        f.printFooNotUsingExceptionHandlerButUsingLogger();
        // call this to throw exception
        f.printFooUsingExceptionHandler();

    } catch( ExceptionHandler& e  ) {
        std::cout << "Exception Thrown: " << e.getMessage() << std::endl;
        quitMessage();
        return ReturnError;
    } catch( ... ) {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " Caught Unknown Exception" << std::endl;
        quitMessage();
        return ReturnError;
    }

    quitMessage();
    return ReturnOkay;
}
```

---

**The Classes:**

---

*`ExceptionHandler.h`*

```
#ifndef EXCEPTION_HANDLER_H
#define EXCEPTION_HANDLER_H

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

namespace linx {

class ExceptionHandler final {
private:
    std::string _message;

public:
    explicit ExceptionHandler( const std::string& message, bool saveInLog = true );
    explicit ExceptionHandler( const std::ostringstream& streamMessage, bool saveInLog = true );

    ~ExceptionHandler() = default;
    ExceptionHandler( const ExceptionHandler& c ) = default;
    ExceptionHandler& operator=( const ExceptionHandler& c ) = delete;

    const std::string& getMessage() const;    
};

} // namespace linx

#endif // !EXCEPTION_HANDLER_H
```

*`ExceptionHandler.cpp`*

```
#include "ExceptionHandler.h"
#include "Logger.h"

namespace linx {

ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler( const std::string& message, bool saveInLog ) : 
_message( message ) {
    if( saveInLog ) {
        Logger::log( _message, Logger::TypeError );
    }
}

ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler( const std::ostringstream& streamMessage, bool saveInLog ) :
_message( streamMessage.str() ) {
    if( saveInLog ) {
        Logger::log( _message, Logger::TypeError );
    }
}

const std::string& ExceptionHandler::getMessage() const {
    return _message;
}

} // namespace linx
```

*`Logger.h`*

```
#include <sstream>
#include <array>

// For Windows Console Output
#define VC_EXTRALEAN 
#include <Windows.h>

namespace linx {

class Logger final : public Singleton {
public:
    enum LoggerType {
        TypeInfo = 0,
        TypeWarning,
        TypeError,
        TypeConsole
    };

private:
    std::string _logFilename;
    unsigned    _maxCharLength;

    std::array<std::string, 4> _logTypes;
    const std::string _unknownLogType;

    // This is for Windows Console Output - Can substitue with OS type
    HANDLE _hConsoleOutput;
    WORD   _consoleDefualtColor;
    // --------------------------------------------------------------- 

public:
    explicit Logger( const std::string& logFilename );
    virtual ~Logger();

    static void log( const std::string& text, LoggerType logType = TypeInfo );
    static void log( const std::ostringstream& text, LoggerType logType = TypeInfo );
    static void log( const char* text, LoggerType logType = TypeInfo );
};

} // namespace linx

#endif // !LOGGER_H
```

*`Logger.cpp`*

```
#include "Logger.h"
#include "TextFileWriter.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <mutex>
// #include <shared_mutex>

namespace linx {

static Logger* s_pLogger = nullptr;

std::mutex  g_mutex;  // also removed the static storage qualifier.
//static std::shared_mutex s_mutex; // this was a wrong implementation

// White Text On Red Background
static const WORD WHITE_ON_RED = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED; 

Logger::Logger( const std::string& logFilename ) :
Singleton( TypeLogger ),
_logFilename( logFilename ),
_maxCharLength( 0 ),
_unknownLogType( "UNKNOWN" ) {
    // Order must match types defined in Logger::LoggerType enum
    _logTypes[0] = "Info";
    _logTypes[1] = "Warning";
    _logTypes[2] = "Error";
    _logTypes[3] = ""; // Console

    // Find widest log type string
    _maxCharLength = _unknownLogType.size();
    for ( const std::string& logType : _logTypes ) {
        if( _maxCharLength < logType.size() ) {
            _maxCharLength = logType.size();
        }
    }

    // this was wrong
    //std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock( s_mutex );

    { // scope for lock_guard
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( g_mutex );

        // Start Log File
        TextFileWriter file( _logFilename, false, false );

        // Prepare Console  - Windows Console (can substitute with your OS)
        _hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleInfo;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( _hConsoleOutput, &consoleInfo );
        _consoleDefualtColor = consoleInfo.wAttributes;
        // End - Windows Console specific

        s_pLogger = this;
    } // end scope: lock_guard must be destroyed here 

    // Must destroy lock_guard to unlock mutex before calling this function
    // this function is derived from Singleton but it calls Logger::log() static method which in turn uses the same mutex to lock.
    logMemoryAllocation( true );
}

Logger::~Logger() {
    logMemoryAllocation( false );
    s_pLogger = nullptr;
}

void Logger::log( const std::string& text, LoggerType logType ) {
    log( text.c_str(), logType );
}

void Logger::log( const std::ostringstream& text, LoggerType logType ) {
    log( text.str().c_str(), logType );
}

void Logger::log( const char* text, LoggerType logType ) {
    if( nullptr == s_pLogger ) {
        std::cout << "Logger has not been initialized, can not log " << text << '\n';
        return;
    }

    // this is wrong
    //std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock( s_mutex );

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( g_mutex );

    std::ostringstream stream;

    // Default White Text On Red Background
    WORD textColor = WHITE_ON_RED;

    // Choose log type text string, display "UNKNOWN" if logType is out of range
    stream << std::setfill( ' ' ) << std::setw( s_pLogger->_maxCharLength );

    try {
        if( TypeConsole != logType ) {
            stream << s_pLogger->_logTypes.at( logType );
        }
        if( TypeWarning == logType ) {
            // Yellow
            textColor = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN;
        } else if( TypeInfo == logType ) {
            // Green
            textColor = FOREGROUND_GREEN;
        } else if( TypeConsole == logType ) {
            // Cyan
            textColor = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE;
        }
    } catch( ... ) {
        stream << s_pLogger->_unknownLogType;
    }

    // Date & Time
    if( TypeConsole != logType ) {
        SYSTEMTIME time;
        GetLocalTime( &time );

        stream << " [" << time.wYear << '.'
            << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wMonth << '.'
            << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wDay << ' '
            << std::setfill( ' ' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wHour << ':'
            << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wMinute << ':'
            << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << time.wSecond << '.'
            << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 3 ) << time.wMilliseconds << "] ";
    }
    stream << text << '\n';

    // Log Message
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( s_pLogger->_hConsoleOutput, textColor );
    std::cout << stream.str();

    // Save same message to file
    try {
        TextFileWriter file( s_pLogger->_logFilename, true, false );
        file.write( stream.str() );
    } catch( ... ) {
        // Ignore, not saved in log file
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " failed to write to file: " << stream.str() << '\n';
    }

    // Reset to default color
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( s_pLogger->_hConsoleOutput, s_pLogger->_consoleDefualtColor );
}

} // namespace linx
```

*`Singleton.h`*

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

namespace linx {

class Singleton {
public:
    enum SingletonType {
        TypeLogger = 0, // MUST BE FIRST!
    };

private:
    SingletonType _type;

public:
    Singleton( const Singleton& c ) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=( const Singleton& c ) = delete;
    virtual ~Singleton();

protected:
    explicit Singleton( SingletonType type );
    void logMemoryAllocation( bool isAllocated ) const;
};

} // namespace linx

#endif // !SINGLETON_H
```

*`Single.cpp`*

```
#include "Singleton.h"
#include "Logger.h"
#include "ExceptionHandler.h"

#include <string>
#include <array>

namespace linx {

struct SingletonInfo {
    const std::string singletonName;
    bool  isConstructed;

    SingletonInfo( const std::string& singletonNameIn ) :
        singletonName( singletonNameIn ),
        isConstructed( false ) {}
};

// Order must match types defined in Singleton::SingletonType
static std::array<SingletonInfo, 1> s_aSingletons = { SingletonInfo( "Logger" ) };

Singleton::Singleton( SingletonType type ) :
_type( type ) {
    bool saveInLog = s_aSingletons.at( TypeLogger ).isConstructed;

    try {
        if( !s_aSingletons.at( type ).isConstructed ) {
            // Test Initialize Order
            for( int i = 0; i < type; ++i ) {
                if( !s_aSingletons.at( i ).isConstructed ) {
                    throw ExceptionHandler( s_aSingletons.at( i ).singletonName +
                                            " must be constructed before constructing " +
                                            s_aSingletons.at( type ).singletonName,
                                            saveInLog );
                }
            }
            s_aSingletons.at( type ).isConstructed = true;
        } else {
            throw ExceptionHandler( s_aSingletons.at( type ).singletonName +
                                    " can only be constructed once.",
                                    saveInLog );
        }
    } catch( std::exception& ) {
        // type is out of range
        std::ostringstream stream;
        stream << __FUNCTION__ << " Invalid Singleton Type specified: " << type;
        throw ExceptionHandler( stream, saveInLog );
    }
}

Singleton::~Singleton() {
    s_aSingletons.at( _type ).isConstructed = false;
}

void Singleton::logMemoryAllocation( bool isAllocated ) const {
    if( isAllocated ) {
        Logger::log( "Created " + s_aSingletons.at( _type ).singletonName );
    }  else {
        Logger::log( "Destroyed " + s_aSingletons.at( _type ).singletonName );
    }   
}

} // namespace linx
```

*`TextFileWriter`*

```
#ifndef TEXT_FILE_WRITER_H
#define TEXT_FILE_WRITER_H

#include "FileHandler.h"

namespace linx {

class TextFileWriter : public FileHandler {
public:
    explicit TextFileWriter( const std::string& filename, bool appendToFile, bool saveExceptionInLog = true );
    virtual ~TextFileWriter() = default;

    void write( const std::string& str );

    TextFileWriter( const TextFileWriter& ) = delete;
    TextFileWriter& operator=( const TextFileWriter& ) = delete;
};

} // namespace linx

#endif // !TEXT_FILE_WRITER_H
```

*`TextFileWriter.cpp`*

```
#include "TextFileWriter.h"

namespace linx {

TextFileWriter::TextFileWriter( const std::string& filename, bool appendToFile, bool saveExceptionInLog ) :
    FileHandler( filename, saveExceptionInLog ) {
    _file.open( _filenameWithPath.c_str(),
                std::ios_base::out | (appendToFile ? std::ios_base::app : std::ios_base::trunc) );
    if( !_file.is_open() ) {
        throwError( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " can not open file for writing" ) );
    }
}

void TextFileWriter::write( const std::string& str ) {
    _file << str;
}

} // namespace linx
```

*`FileHandler.h`*

```
#ifndef FILE_HANDLER_H
#define FILE_HANDLER_H

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

namespace linx {

class FileHandler {
private:
    bool _saveExceptionInLog;

protected:
    std::fstream _file;
    std::string  _filePath;
    std::string  _filenameWithPath;

public:
    virtual ~FileHandler();

    FileHandler( const FileHandler& c ) = delete;
    FileHandler& operator=( const FileHandler& c ) = delete;

protected:
    FileHandler( const std::string& filename, bool saveExceptionInLog );
    void throwError( const std::string& message ) const;
    void throwError( const std::ostringstream& message ) const;

    bool getString( std::string& str, bool appendPath );
}; 

} // namespace linx

#endif // !FILE_HANDLER_H
```

*`FileHandler.cpp`*

```
#include "ExceptionHandler.h"
#include "Logger.h"

namespace linx {

ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler( const std::string& message, bool saveInLog ) : 
_message( message ) {
    if( saveInLog ) {
        Logger::log( _message, Logger::TypeError );
    }
}

ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler( const std::ostringstream& streamMessage, bool saveInLog ) :
_message( streamMessage.str() ) {
    if( saveInLog ) {
        Logger::log( _message, Logger::TypeError );
    }
}

const std::string& ExceptionHandler::getMessage() const {
    return _message;
}

} // namespace linx
```

Comment: There was a bug in the above program. It was in my logger class that pertained to the shared_lock & shared_mutex that were being used. You can refer to the class and comments for the changes made.